# GDI+ Graphics::DrawImage doesn't work

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to draw an image using GDI+. When I do it inside `WM_PAINT` it works:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Gdiplus::Image gdiImage(L"unt.png");
    graphics.DrawImage(&gdiImage, 40, 40);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    break;

}
```

But when I do it on a button click or inside `WM_CREATE` it doesn't draw the image:

```
HDC hdc2 = GetDC(hWnd);
Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc2);
Gdiplus::Image gdiImage(L"unt.png");
graphics.DrawImage(&gdiImage, 40, 40);
```

Even if I use `BeginPaint()` and `EndPaint()` it still fails. So, is there any way to draw the image outside of `WM_PAINT`?

Comment: If you do it in WM_CREATE then you do it too early, the window isn't visible yet.  When you do it in a button click handler then it probably works but you just can't see it because it gets over-painted again a millisecond later.  Well, that's why WM_PAINT exists, it reliably tells you when you *should* paint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Win32, almost all drawing must happen in WM_PAINT handler. 
Probably you don't see any drawing because as soon you finish to handle the button click, you receive a WM_PAINT.

If you draw outside WM_PAINT your drawing have short life because of invalidation of windows and then WM_PAINT message.

So the correct way to draw in Win32 is the WM_PAINT handler.

I edited the answer after a comment of author.
Suppose you need to change the image after a mouse click. You can do:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Gdiplus::Image gdiImage(clicked ? L"image_A.png" : L"image_B.png");
    graphics.DrawImage(&gdiImage, 40, 40);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;

}
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
    clicked = true;
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
    break;
}
```

The InvalidateRect function is the answer. With that function you tell to Windows to redraw the window. This is the link to man page:[InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: In that case, how can I draw an image on button click or simply on window creation?

Comment: Because when I draw inside WM_PAINT. Image drawing only when I resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update an image based on a button click (or any other Windows Event handler for that matter), you have to invalidate the area that the image occupies on the screen—usually through `InvalidateRect()`—and then have your `WM_PAINT` handler draw the image.

Comment: I used this but still fails: RECT rcClient;
   GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
   InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rcClient, true);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

Comment: @DimChtz you don't need to get the client rect, just pass `NULL` to `InvalidateRect`. And no need to call `UpdateWindow`, Windows will generate a `WM_PAINT` message automatically.